# How to use Task.await with GenServer?

Tags: elixir, gen-server

I am trying to figure out how to start a genserver, and wait for the result until it finishes.

How would I make the server return a result when it exits?

like for example:

```
defmodule DistanceMatrix do
  use GenServer

  def start id do
    GenServer.start(__MODULE__, id)
  end

  def load() do
    GenServer.cast({:load})
  end

  def handle_cast({:load}, state) do
    # start long process operation
    long_process
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  def long_process do
    :timer.sleep 2000
    %{result: "Process result.."}
  end

end 


results= ids
|> Enum.map(fn id -> DistanceMatrix.start(id) end)
|> Enum.map(&Task.await/1)
|> Enum.map(fn({:ok, result}) -> 
   result
   end)
```

So, how would I wait and get the result?

Comment: How about changing all `cast` to `call` and calling `load` instead of `Task.await`?

Comment: I want to process all ids in the same time, I've tried `call`, but I got ids processed sequentially instead of parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way: in the `:load` `cast`, return the result of `long_process` as the new state. Then add a `call` which just returns the current state (named `:get` below). Since a GenServer processes messages sequentially in the order they're sent, the `:get` call will block until the previous `:load` is complete.

```
defmodule DistanceMatrix do
  use GenServer

  def start(id) do
    GenServer.start(__MODULE__, id)
  end

  def load(pid) do
    GenServer.cast(pid, {:load})
    pid
  end

  def await(pid), do: GenServer.call(pid, :get)

  def init(id), do: {:ok, id}

  def handle_call(:get, _, state), do: {:reply, state, state}

  def handle_cast({:load}, _state) do
    {:noreply, long_process()}
  end

  def long_process do
    :timer.sleep(2000)
    %{result: "Process result.."}
  end
end

1..10
|> Enum.map(fn id ->
  {:ok, pid} = DistanceMatrix.start(id)
  pid
end)
|> Enum.map(&DistanceMatrix.load/1)
|> Enum.map(&DistanceMatrix.await/1)
|> Enum.map(fn result ->
  IO.inspect(result)
end)
```

Output:

```
%{result: "Process result.."}
%{result: "Process result.."}
%{result: "Process result.."}
%{result: "Process result.."}
%{result: "Process result.."}
%{result: "Process result.."}
%{result: "Process result.."}
%{result: "Process result.."}
%{result: "Process result.."}
%{result: "Process result.."}
```

The program takes a little over 2 seconds, as expected.